# Model an "active participants" type usage with Stripe

Tags: stripe-payments

I am trying to understand the best way to model a monthly subscription where customers pay for the number of "Active" participants (similar to a user, but irrelevant).

Participants can be marked as active or inactive, and we want to prorate the usage.

Eg for a billing period 2023-09-23 to 2023-10-23:

Participant ABC was marked as Active on 2023-09-29 and marked Inactive on 2023-10-20. There usage would thus be 21 days.

Participant DEF was marked as Active on 2023-09-28 and marked Inactive on 2023-09-30. There usage would thus be 2 days.

I want to charge $10 per active Participant, per month, prorated. So the bill for this period would be: (21/30 * 10) + (2/30 * 10) = $7.66

Does this make sense? How would you model this in Stripe? Is Stripe able to handle the prorate itself?

I'm not yet at the stage of trying anything as this is a design problem

Answer (score 0):

yes Stripe supports [prorations](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/prorations) and in fact this is the default behaviour for subscriptions.

You can start with the basic [flat rate](https://stripe.com/docs/products-prices/pricing-models#flat-rate) billing model, in which your customer will be billed with the full amount ($10) when the subscription starts (2023-09-23). When you cancel the subscription earlier (i.e., on 2023-10-20) than the next renewal date, Stripe will prorate it and returns the difference to the customer as [credit balance](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/customer/balance), which can be automatically applied to the next invoice of the same customer.

If you prefer to charge the customer at the end of the billing cycle, or when you cancel the subscription, consider using [usage-based model](https://stripe.com/docs/products-prices/pricing-models#usage-based-pricing). Remember to [report usage](https://stripe.com/docs/products-prices/pricing-models#reporting-usage) within the current billing peroid.

Comment: Hi @quichan. Thanks for your answer. Just so we're clear, this works with usage items? I.e. customers can have hundreds of participants. In the above example (which is admittedly not that clear), the customer has 1 subscription, and during that billing period, they had 2 participants (one for 2 days, one for 21 days, overlapping)

Comment: This won't work with metered billing. Metered billing does not compute prorations. It also doesn't allow you to charge for usage in the way you want there, you can only set it to charge for the sum of all units / latest usage record (based on `aggregation_mode`). This will however work correctly with licenced prices (note however that Stripe handles prorations in terms of 'remaining' and 'unused' time, so while prorations will give you the correct result, it might not be as clear as what you were hoping from an Invoice item description standpoint.

Comment: Hi @DominicBou-Samra Prorations are created only for licensed (per-seat) subscriptions because they’re billed at the start of each billing period, and no prorations are created for post-paid subscriptions (i.e., usage-based billing). Sorry I wasn't clear earlier, you need to report usage for usage-based model, which means you need to calculate the amount based on the customer's usage and report accordingly.

Comment: Hi @qichuan. Yeah, figured as much. Thanks for your help!